# Ignoring None values when calling dumps on a marshmallow schema

Tags: python, marshmallow

I am using a marshmallow schema. One of the member variables is created like so

`uc = fields.Integer(data_key='uc', description='the description')`

At some point I use this schema to dump a class as JSON, something like

`json=schema_instance.dumps(my_class)`

This all works fine. However sometimes my_class.uc is None. Is there a way to ignore None values when it comes to creating the JSON? .. at the moment it includes it like so

`...'uc': null...`

in this case uc is optional and I would like it to be excluded

Answer (score -1):

There is special parameter **skip_none**.

```
  json_data = schema_instance.dumps(my_class, skip_none=True)
```

https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/marshalling.html

Especially funciton, which taking input_dict and removing **None**, **null**, **undefined**.

```
def remove_none_undefined(input_dict):
    return {key: value for key, value in input_dict.items() if value is not None and value != null and value != undefined}
```

Comment: That looks like a different marshmallow lib (?)  https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/marshmallow.schema.html#marshmallow.schema.Schema.dumps   is the one we use.

Comment: also i added the function, which remove null, undefined and none.

Comment: It's in the case, when this version of software doesn't include skip_none flag.